# Access denied errors occurring when running a Gitlab build

Tags: docker, gitlab, maven

I am running a self- hosted Gitlab server from a Docker container. For CI/CD, I am running gitlab-runner in a docker container as well. My version of Gitlab is V16.5.2.

My runner is set up to use dockerized Maven in order to build a Spring Boot application (in other words, the runner has an executor of "docker").  The gitlab-ci.yml file contains the following:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository

image: maven:latest

stages:
    - build

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target

build_job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - defender 

  script: 
    - echo "Maven compile started"
    - "mvn compile"
```

When attempting to do the build, I getting consistent failures. The log of my build attempts is provided below:

```
section_start:1699378398:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image maven:latest ...[0;m
[0KPulling docker image maven:latest ...[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:6f90e67c6517ddbfbd701490443ca2645964d5a4da0382e9c144ecfaaa972d4b for maven:latest with digest maven@sha256:e0900e5953fddc181fdbe449ba8c27f124470fb545fbbb29f39f50d6093c9b18 ...[0;m
section_end:1699378401:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1699378401:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-siwnpzrb-project-19-concurrent-0 via c734e0f780f9...
section_end:1699378402:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1699378402:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/research/project-06/project-06d/configsrv/.git/
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://git.solishome.net/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.solishome.net/research/project-06/project-06d/configsrv.git/'
section_end:1699378403:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1699378403:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1699378404:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

I am not using 2- factor authentication on my runner. The runner was properly registered using the registration token provided by my Gitlab instance.

One weird thing I notice is that while I am configured to use https for accessing my Gitlab instance, the failed authentication is using http for access. Is this part of the problem?

Can anyone tell me how I can stop these authentication failures?

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the error message:
https://docs.gitlab.com/16.5/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#troubleshooting

Have you verified these also don't apply to you?

```
You do not have 2FA enabled and have sent an incorrect username or password with your request.

You do not have 2FA enabled but an administrator has enabled the enforce 2FA for all users setting.

You do not have 2FA enabled, but an administrator has disabled the password authentication enabled for Git over HTTP(S) setting.
```

You can also try running your pipeline with CI_DEBUG_TRACE set to true as a pipeline variable and it'll show debug logs for the clone process, just keep in mind if you have un-masked credentials or other env secrets they may be visible, ref:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#enable-debug-logging

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).